# the 'form' of two physical quantities VS the 'forms' of two physical quantities

Tags: word-usage

When reading academic papers, I always come across the doubts like 'the noun' vs 'the nouns', which seem difficult for me to tell which one is best to choose as a non-native person.  Can anyone help me clarify the difference between '***form***' of two physical quantities and the '***forms***' of two physical quantities in the sentence 'the form / the forms is / are represented by vector notation'?

Comment: Neither is ungrammatical. One is a deleted form of ''The form of each of these physical quantities is represented by vector notation" and the other of  ''The forms of these [two] physical quantities are represented by vector notation" . If there are two different forms (ie if you want to stress significant differences), use the second variant. If one, I'd use the first. / However, I'd just say 'These two quantities are represented using a 2-by-1 matrix' / vector notation' etc.

Comment: Thanks. Edwin. It seems the deleted form of words is often used when I'm reading.  Is there any dedicated grammatical rule for this usage? 'the form of each sth' seems more clearer for me to make sense, because in my language, there is no difference in word form of objects.

Comment: Sorry, Wenjin Xing (can one respectfully drop either of those?) – it takes a long lifetime to become even reasonably proficient. And grey areas always crop up. But look at articles here on 'deletion' as a start. You might also find articles on 'notional agreement' helpful.

Comment: That's fine. Wenjin is my given name, and Xing is my last name. You can call me either. No disrespect here. Thanks for your help. It really help me a lot.